# staying still in UEE

Tags: diablo-iii-console

Is there a button you can press to keep your character stationary while attacking in the console version of Diablo 3?

I liked being able to hold shift on PC and attack while keeping my character still. Is there anything like that on console?

Comment: It appears there is no way to get the same functionality. I would suggest instead just switching that skill to a different slot that allows the directional pad and button to fire in the direction you want.

Comment: As movement is different (stick vs. clicking), with a separate button for attacking (A/X vs. clicking), I don't think a 'stay stationary' key is needed as one button is not overloaded.  
What is your use case?  The only one I could see was wanting to rotate and attack while staying still.

Answer (score 2):

As mmatthews already commented: If you don't move the left stick, you won't move. Except if you have a skill that teleports. Or you are teleported by the enemy.